# Android - show TextView when the GridView is empty

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have favorite page with gridview for wallpaper app.
sometimes this page for user is empty

I wanna show the textview "There is no item" when the gridview is empty

what should i do?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a TextView as empty view.

```
TextView emptyView = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
emptyView.setText("There is no item");
gridView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

This will show the empty message when GridView is empty.